# ordering records by time

Tags: couchdb

I created a simple view to return the blog title and time

```
function(doc) {
if ( doc.TITLE) emit(doc.TIME, doc.TITLE);
```

}

what is a simple way to display newest blog articles first (by default it is the other way around)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just apply `descending` sort order at view request e.g.

```
GET /dbname/_design/titles/_view/by_time?descending=True
```

And view output would be sorted in reversed way - newest blog articles will go first. Remember that startkey/endkey parameters will limit key range for this reversed order. More about view query parameters you could found in [CouchDB wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options)